# Poor I/O utilisation with rsync, RAID6 and ext4

Tags: rsync, ext4, raid

I noticed poor I/O utilization when rsync'ing from an external HDD (connected with USB 3.0) to a RAID6 (4 HDDs) with ext4. iostat shows that reading from the USB HDD happens for most part at 110 MB/s (that's in line with specs). iostat also shows that for about 50% of the time, nothing is written to the RAID. At some point writing to the RAID starts and soon after reading from the USB HDD stops (0 MB/s). This goes on for a few seconds, then reading from the USB resumes and writing to the RAID stops. It seems like a write cache is blocking. How do I debug this issue?

System is Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-136-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the system was configured to minimise disk writes through a large write cache. The settings `vm.dirty_ratio` (% of cache that has to fill up before a blocking write-out happens) and `vm.dirty_background_ratio` (% of cache at which a non-blocking write-out starts) were set to 90 which queues data until it is either flushed or 90% of available memory is full. Setting `vm.dirty_background_ratio` to 1 solved the issue.